# LINQ Code that counts employee gender in each position and group by department and place in a matrix table

Tags: linq, html-table, count, grouping, multiple-columns

I just want to ask on how to create an LINQ code that can fill up my html table.

Please look at my Tables below

Table EMP: note* my "Male" is boolean

```
+----+---------------+--------+--------+
| id | Male| JS_REF  |DEPT_ID | POS_ID |
+----+---------------+--------+--------+
|  1 | 1   |   1     |   2    |   3    |
|  2 | 0   |   2     |   2    |   3    |
|  3 | 1   |   3     |   1    |   2    |
|  4 | 1   |   2     |   4    |   2    |
|  5 | 1   |   1     |   5    |   5    |
|  6 | 0   |   4     |   6    |   1    |
|  7 | 1   |   1     |   1    |   1    |
|  8 | 0   |   2     |   2    |   3    |
+----+---------------+--------+--------+
```

Table:JOB_STATUS

```
+----+--------------------+
| id | JS_REF| JS_TITLE   |
+----+--------------------+
|  1 | 1     |Undefined   |
|  2 | 2     |Regular     |
|  3 | 3     |Contructual |
|  4 | 4     |Probationary|
+----+--------------------+
```

Table:DEPTS

```
+----+--------------------+
| id | DEPT_ID| DEPT_NAME |
+----+--------------------+
|  1 | 1     |Admin       |
|  2 | 2     |Accounting  |
|  3 | 3     |Eginnering  |
|  4 | 4     |HR          |
+----+--------------------+
```

Table: POSITIONS

```
+----+--------------------+
| id |  POS_ID| DEPT_NAME |
+----+--------------------+
|  1 | 1     |Clerk       |
|  2 | 2     |Accountant  |
|  3 | 3     |Bookeeper   |
|  4 | 4     |Assistant   |
|  5 | 5     |Mechanic    |
|  6 | 6     |Staff       |
+----+--------------------+
```

I'd made a static table on what will be the outcome of the LINQ code

Here's the picture: [image: outcome]

Here's what i've tried so far:

```
SELECT  tb.DEPT_NAME,TB.JS_TITLE, TB.Male, TB.Female, (TB.Male + TB.Female) AS 'Total Employees' FROM
(
    SELECT JS_TITLE,DEPT_NAME,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MALE = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Male,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MALE = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Female
    FROM   EMP 
    left join JOB_STATUS on JOB_STATUS.JS_REF = EMP.JS_REF
    left join DEPTS on DEPTS.DEPT_ID = EMP.DEPT_ID
    GROUP BY JS_TITLE,DEPT_NAME
) AS TB
ORDER BY CASE WHEN TB.MALE IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

If anyone can help me or give me some tips on how can I implement this im stuck in this part.

*101 is total count for male, 23 for female. (the values are just copy and pasted, that's why the values are the same)*

*(Actual data result)*[image: Actual Data]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: What does e.g. the `HR` being spread across multiple rows mean for the final Linq result? Do you expect nested classes, or should it be flat? What does the `101` and `23` mean and how does it correlate to your sample data? Can you show the actual results from the sample data? I can trivially make some LINQ generate 101 and 23 in rows...

Comment: @NetMage I've edited and uploaded the actual result in my post

Comment: @Phong I like to use LINQ, but since i'm new to it, i'm trying with SQL Query. I've updated in my post what i've tried so far

Comment: Since you say you are trying SQL, are you using Linq to SQL or EF? If EF, which one:  EF 6.x / EF Core 2.0 / EF Core 2.1 / EF Core 3.x?

Comment: Your added output is not helpful since it still doesn't match up to your sample data. Please provide sample data and results that match.